# Cloudflare Pages, create-react-app build error: The engine "node" is incompatible with this module

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, cloudflare

My react app builds fine in dev, but when attempting to deploy it on CloudFlare Pages, I encounter a build error message: The engine "node" is incompatible with this module. Expected version "18.7.0". Got "16.19.0" Found incompatible module.

Please see the full build log below.

Build config:

```
Build command:  yarn build
Build output directory:  /build
Root directory:  /
Build comments on pull requests:  Enabled

Environment variables:
Variable name:  NODE_VERSION    Value:  16.19.0
```

Cloudflare build log:

```
2023-02-27T19:15:45.363078Z Cloning repository...
2023-02-27T19:15:47.000973Z From https://github.com/codecaviette/portfolio-project
2023-02-27T19:15:47.001598Z  * branch            5707e11c7311c3b0f8b20f2018636d0221e3a12a -> FETCH_HEAD
2023-02-27T19:15:47.001819Z 
2023-02-27T19:15:47.116928Z HEAD is now at 5707e11 Remove codepen social media icon, add medium icon
2023-02-27T19:15:47.117499Z 
2023-02-27T19:15:47.273285Z 
2023-02-27T19:15:47.302902Z Success: Finished cloning repository files
2023-02-27T19:15:47.98Z Installing dependencies
2023-02-27T19:15:47.994187Z Python version set to 2.7
2023-02-27T19:15:51.462082Z Downloading and installing node v16.19.0...
2023-02-27T19:15:51.890238Z Downloading https://nodejs.org/dist/v16.19.0/node-v16.19.0-linux-x64.tar.xz...
2023-02-27T19:15:52.34036Z  Computing checksum with sha256sum
2023-02-27T19:15:52.473562Z Checksums matched!
2023-02-27T19:15:56.99937Z  Now using node v16.19.0 (npm v8.19.3)
2023-02-27T19:15:57.409813Z Started restoring cached build plugins
2023-02-27T19:15:57.423901Z Finished restoring cached build plugins
2023-02-27T19:15:57.929583Z Attempting ruby version 2.7.1, read from environment
2023-02-27T19:16:01.660589Z Using ruby version 2.7.1
2023-02-27T19:16:02.032316Z Using PHP version 5.6
2023-02-27T19:16:02.20657Z  5.2 is already installed.
2023-02-27T19:16:02.233669Z Using Swift version 5.2
2023-02-27T19:16:02.234385Z Started restoring cached node modules
2023-02-27T19:16:02.252065Z Finished restoring cached node modules
2023-02-27T19:16:02.259523Z Started restoring cached yarn cache
2023-02-27T19:16:02.273866Z Finished restoring cached yarn cache
2023-02-27T19:16:02.295294Z Installing yarn at version 1.22.4
2023-02-27T19:16:02.313576Z [37mInstalling Yarn![0m
2023-02-27T19:16:02.313917Z [36m> Downloading tarball...[0m
2023-02-27T19:16:02.358755Z 
2023-02-27T19:16:02.359119Z [1/2]: https://yarnpkg.com/downloads/1.22.4/yarn-v1.22.4.tar.gz --> /tmp/yarn.tar.gz.C7UvybHLqD
2023-02-27T19:16:02.359835Z   % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
2023-02-27T19:16:02.360151Z                                  Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
2023-02-27T19:16:02.596854Z 
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
100    80  100    80    0     0    337      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   337
2023-02-27T19:16:02.730301Z 
100    93  100    93    0     0    250      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   250
2023-02-27T19:16:03.075892Z 
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
2023-02-27T19:16:03.39148Z  
 62 1215k   62  758k    0     0   757k      0  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:--  757k
100 1215k  100 1215k    0     0  1177k      0  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:-- 14.4M
2023-02-27T19:16:03.391825Z 
2023-02-27T19:16:03.392036Z [2/2]: https://yarnpkg.com/downloads/1.22.4/yarn-v1.22.4.tar.gz.asc --> /tmp/yarn.tar.gz.C7UvybHLqD.asc
2023-02-27T19:16:03.421691Z 
100    84  100    84    0     0   2883      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  2883
2023-02-27T19:16:03.424204Z 
100    96  100    96    0     0   3023      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  3023
2023-02-27T19:16:03.435952Z 
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
2023-02-27T19:16:03.519434Z 
100  1028  100  1028    0     0   8096      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  8096
2023-02-27T19:16:03.568734Z [36m> Verifying integrity...[0m
2023-02-27T19:16:03.608937Z gpg: Signature made Mon 09 Mar 2020 03:52:13 PM UTC using RSA key ID 69475BAA
2023-02-27T19:16:03.615122Z gpg: Good signature from "Yarn Packaging <yarn@dan.cx>"
2023-02-27T19:16:03.617621Z gpg: Note: This key has expired!
2023-02-27T19:16:03.617915Z Primary key fingerprint: 72EC F46A 56B4 AD39 C907  BBB7 1646 B01B 86E5 0310
2023-02-27T19:16:03.618072Z      Subkey fingerprint: 6D98 490C 6F1A CDDD 448E  4595 4F77 6793 6947 5BAA
2023-02-27T19:16:03.618844Z [32m> GPG signature looks good[0m
2023-02-27T19:16:03.619095Z [36m> Extracting to ~/.yarn...[0m
2023-02-27T19:16:03.720168Z [36m> Adding to $PATH...[0m
2023-02-27T19:16:03.748749Z [36m> We've added the following to your /opt/buildhome/.bashrc
2023-02-27T19:16:03.749145Z > If this isn't the profile of your current shell then please add the following to your correct profile:
2023-02-27T19:16:03.749367Z    
2023-02-27T19:16:03.749544Z export PATH="$HOME/.yarn/bin:$HOME/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/.bin:$PATH"
2023-02-27T19:16:03.750689Z [0m
2023-02-27T19:16:04.152705Z [32m> Successfully installed Yarn 1.22.4! Please open another terminal where the `yarn` command will now be available.[0m
2023-02-27T19:16:04.562632Z Installing NPM modules using Yarn version 1.22.4
2023-02-27T19:16:05.092859Z npm WARN config tmp This setting is no longer used.  npm stores temporary files in a special
2023-02-27T19:16:05.093186Z npm WARN config location in the cache, and they are managed by
2023-02-27T19:16:05.093364Z npm WARN config     [`cacache`](http://npm.im/cacache).
2023-02-27T19:16:05.350883Z yarn install v1.22.4
2023-02-27T19:16:05.45106Z  [1/5] Validating package.json...
2023-02-27T19:16:05.45573Z  error portfolio-project-react@0.1.0: The engine "node" is incompatible with this module. Expected version "18.7.0". Got "16.19.0"
2023-02-27T19:16:05.466924Z error Found incompatible module.
2023-02-27T19:16:05.467245Z info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install for documentation about this command.
2023-02-27T19:16:05.477208Z Error during Yarn install
2023-02-27T19:16:05.48116Z  Failed: build command exited with code: 1
2023-02-27T19:16:06.502813Z Failed: an internal error occurred
```

Initially, I had node engines (in package.json) and the environmental variable (in cloudflare settings) set to `v18.7.0`. I then read [here](https://www.stackoverflow.com/) that node v18 is not compatible with Cloudflare, so I edited my node versions to be `>=16.0.0` in my package.json and `v16.19.0` in the env var of cloudflare.

I'm unsure how to proceed from here. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you able to fix this?